# Object binding to listbox does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

At the moment i try, to build something like that with WPF ! Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuU06.png

I have a ObservableCollection with my "Wecker" Objects. I want to dynamicly add items to the listbox with DataBinding that looks like in the Screenshot. Every try failed so far. What do i need to set in the XAML File??

```
public static ObservableCollection<Wecker> WeckerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Wecker>();

public ObservableCollection<Wecker> MyWeckerCollection
{
    get { return WeckerCollection; }
}
```

Wecker Class

```
public class Wecker
{
    public ArrayList dayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime Alarm { get; set; }
    public bool activated { get; set; }
    public bool loop { get; set; }
    public int maxRunTime { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool schlummern { get; set; }
    public bool antiStandby { get; set; }
    public bool activateMonitor { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string Mp3 { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool ShowMessage { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; } }
```

I tryed that last time:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="392" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431" Margin="15,89,0,0"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding MyWeckerCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding activated, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Alarm}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding dayOfWeek}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Message}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Mp3}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: You'll need to show the Xaml you have so far so that people are not forced to start from square 1.

Comment: edited the first post

Comment: Just to be clear, you are successfully adding items to the bound collection, and the UI is not updating? Your code looks fine...

Comment: DataContext is {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} Do i need to change it ? Then to what value? The MyWeckerCollection??

Comment: No that looks ok (and if you see the initial objects then the DataContext must be fine). Is it *just* the add that is breaking or do you not get any data at all?

Comment: I am not getting any Data at all and i checked the object, "WeckerCollection" it has Data BEFORE setting it as the DataContext

Comment: You did a relative source binding, are you sure about that? The data context would get set right after the constructor invocation, and you assign to an empty list. How are you assigning the initial data?

Comment: @Diablo What UI object binds the `DataContext` in that way? And what object contains the `MyWeckerCollection` property?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try to add the ItemSource to your ListBox and change the Xaml like this :
Code behind :

```
this.YourList.ItemsSource = WeckerCollection;
```

Xaml :

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="392" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431" Margin="15,89,0,0"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Comment: That would bind to the DataContext itself, and the code-behind would overwrite this (or be overwritten depending on where that line is put). This has next to 0 chance of helping anything, and is certainly semantically confusing.

Comment: So then the binding engine comes around and assigns ItemsSource to the DataContext itself. Definitely not what you want, and still very semantically confusing (you have two sets, which applies? It depends on order, which is very bad)

Comment: @Diablo, I **strongly** suspect there is something else going on here that you *need* to understand going forward, even though you apparently have it working (how with this code I don't know). I would still recommend checking your initial set. It is probably coming after the binding occurs and you don't implement INotifyPropertyChagned

Comment: Setting the `ItemsSource` property through code-behind like this is not the same as `Binding` it, and it is not a maintainable long-term solution. The correct way to do this would be to ensure your `DataContext` for your `ListBox` is correct, and to bind the `ItemsSource` the way you are with `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyWeckerCollection}" ... />`

Comment: The second one you have ItemsSource="{Binding}". This binds directly to the DataContext (which is not a collection) and so is *wrong*. Remove that from your answer and I will remove the downvote. Setting the ItemsSource like that is indicative of a separate problem, so I still claim the answer isn't very good (but at least not dangerous without the dual-setting).

Comment: @GayotFow I'm pretty sure [Blam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23789090/302677) is correct that the `DataContext` is not set correctly, however its hard to provide a good suggestion for how to set the `DataContext` correctly since we're given no information on where `MyWeckerCollection` exists, or the type of object where `DataContext` is being bound on.

Comment: I have edited the post to remove the offending binding. Still not good design, but its obvious what it will do now.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have not set the DataContext

In the ctor set the DataContext

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

or you can do it in XAML in the Window (top) section

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
```

If you had set the DataContext then that should work
Are you sure it is in the Windows section

Try (but Path is the default property so that should not be a problem)

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyWeckerCollection}"
```

This may be your problem - public static?
What is the purpose of public static here?

```
public static ObservableCollection<Wecker> WeckerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Wecker>();
```

If you want to use a backing property then do it like this

```
private ObservableCollection<Wecker> myWeckerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Wecker>();
public  ObservableCollection<Wecker> MyWeckerCollection
{
    get { return myWeckerCollection ; }
}
```

Comment: DataContext is {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} Do i need to change it ? Then to what value? The MyWeckerCollection??

Comment: @Diablo Binding to `Self` binds to the UI object. Does your UI object contain the `MyWeckerCollection` property? For example, `<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">` would set the `DataContext` to the `Window` class, however `Window` does not have a property called `MyWeckerCollection`, so your binding would fail. However if you had `<local:MyCustomWindow DataContext="{RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">` and `MyCustomWindow` has a property called `MyWeckerCollection`, then it would work.

Comment: @Blam I had the same thought that the `static` keyword looked very out of place here and could be contributing to the problem, however I ran a quick test and using `static` does not prevent the property from being bound correctly, or from updating properly.

Comment: @Rachel Still would like to know what the purpose is.  The OP is not giving the whole story.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your `DataContext` is set incorrectly.

You say you are binding the `DataContext` to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`, however that just binds the `DataContext` to the UI object itself.

For example,

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

would set the `DataContext` to the Window object, however the class `Window` does not have a property called `MyWeckerCollection`, so your binding would fail.

If you had

```
<local:MyCustomWindow DataContext="{RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

and `MyCustomWindow` has a property called `MyWeckerCollection`, then it would work.

I also see [your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788887/object-binding-to-listbox-does-not-work#comment36587770_23788887) which states:

> I am not getting any Data at all and i checked the object, "WeckerCollection" it has Data BEFORE setting it as the DataContext

This leads me to believe that either

A) `MyWeckerCollection` is not a UI control, in which case you need to update your `DataContext` binding to something other than `Self` so it correctly binds to your object containing `MyWeckerCollection` instead of to the UI object.

B) Or this comment can be read as you are setting the `DataContext` to `MyWeckerCollection` itself, and of course the class `ObservableCollection<Wecker>` does not itself have a property called `MyWeckerCollection`, so the binding would fail.

So the root cause of your problem is the `DataContext` is not being set correctly.

Unfortunately, the information you provided is not enough for us to help to identify the correct way to set the `DataContext`, however if you can provide us with [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788887/object-binding-to-listbox-does-not-work#comment36588380_23788887) I'd be glad to help you out.

Often Visual Studio's binding errors and/or Debug mode is enough to point you in the right direction for fixing the `DataContext`, or there are some 3rd party tools out there like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) which I'd highly recommend for debugging binding errors.

Also if you're new to WPF (which it sounds like you are), and are struggling to understand the purpose of the `DataContext` and how it works, I'd suggest a blog article of mine written for beginners: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). Its very important that you understand the `DataContext` if you are going to be working with WPF. :)